# File field upload in modal/dialog

Tags: 7, ajax, files

I have a custom content type with file field as one of the fields. For theming/UI purposes I should make this file field as clickable button. And only when user clicks on it, he/she gets modal window with upload/file browse or file name if there already is a file uploaded.

I've accomplished this with using jQuery Update module and from there with help of jQurey UI Dialog (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and custom module with JS code:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.module_custom = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
//appending button
var $inputButton = $('<input type="button" value="Līgums" id="open_modal" />');
$inputButton.insertAfter($(".field-name-field-file"));
//hiding file upload wrapper div
$('.field-name-field-file').hide(); 

//initializing modal dialog window   
$( ".field-name-field-file" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  },
  width: 500
});

//launching modal dialog when button is clicked
$( "#open_modal" ).click(function() {
  $( ".field-name-field-file" ).dialog( "open" );
});

  }); 

}
  };
    }(jQuery));
```

This all works from UI/theming perspective but it brakes file upload. When modal window opens and file is uploaded I got error "An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (8 MB) that this server supports." no matter how small file is (event if it is 1 KB). I suppose this issue is related how AJAX upload is handled. Any ideas what is issue here?

Answer (score 0):

For sure this is due to some problem with your sever setting, contact your web hosting company and talk with them regarding the issue.

It could be due to ModSecurity that scans incoming *http* requests for any malicious scripts. There may be an issue with the script causing mod_security to stop the script. ModSecurity is an is an open sourceweb application firewall Apache module, which help in providing an external security layer that increases security, and help in preventing attacks.

In the event that mod_security is causing the error, you will need to contact tech support to have them look at the logs to see what is exactly causing mod_security to flag the uploaded file. You may need to Disable mod_security via cPanel Modsec Manager on your specific domain if there is no work around. Otherwise, tech support will need do this for you.

The other reason could be the size you are allow to upload that can be change in your server setting. It is also important to check apache max_execution_time.

If you have control over your server then you can try to change your php file

post_max_size = 128M upload_max_filesize = 32M max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M

[Source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128939/the-uploaded-file-likely-exceeded-the-maximum-file-size-32-mb-that-this-server)

If not solved then Other Reason May be :
**Check the .htaccess or settings.php for conflicting Code**
Edit the .htaccess file to see if there are any overrides in the code. Some server configurations allow .htaccess settings to override your file upload size. Comment any code that controls the files upload size and save the changes.

The settings.php file also can hold overrides for the file upload size. Edit the settings.php directly on the server or you can change the settings through the Drupal dashboard by going to **Administer > Site configuration > File uploads** and updating the settings from there.

Comment: But this does not happen when I do not use modal window.